# What is the command to show only subversion revisions that have modifications

Tags: svn

When I execute `svn log` I get all the revisions that include revisions that didn't do any modification to the file structure. For example creating branch from current branch. In below image I have marked what I want to omit. Is there any way to get only these revisions using `svn log` command.

[image]

Comment: There are no options in http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html to support this. Depending on the environment you are working in, you may do a shell script to support this, but this is not an easy task.

Comment: @mliebelt thanks for the comment. As a work around I used `svn log -g -v --xml subversion_url`.then read the xml file for each log entry to see if there are any any file modification. this approach is too slow. that's why I needed an another way.